# Cannot copy from ubuntu terminal (not a shortcut misunderstanding)

Tags: command-line, keyboard

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop on a new machine and am having some trouble with the terminal which is turning out to be way more annoying than I expected. I can't copy highlighted text, not with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shortcut or with a right-click and "copy". Neither of these seem to do anything at all, as the clipboard retains the previously copied text. This is the first time I have encountered this problem with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may very well be experiencing [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1722121) where launching Terminal by right-clicking on desktop and selecting "Open Terminal" causes weird behaviours. Failure to copy/paste properly is one of the symptoms.

As a workaround you may launch Terminal always by other means, e.g. by running `gnome-terminal` or opening from the "Activities"/"Show Applications" etc.